# do we have command to delete all files and directories of directory in windows command prompt

Tags: batch-file

I found one command

delete /f *

But this command has problem that it asks user to enter yes or No as confirmation prompt, after hitting command.

Do we have any other variant of this command to delete files and directories recursively & empty current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, is your `delete` command actually `del`?

Then, to solve the prompting problem, you can bypass it with:

```
echo y| del /f * > nul
```

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. Yes I meant del command

Answer (score 1):

I also found one more way to achieve it

del /q /f *

/q : refers to quiet mode
/f : parameter to indicate file name inputs
"*"   : wild chare to indicate all present files

Comment: Yes.  It helps if you actually read the help file for the command you are trying to use.  Since the dawn of most operating systems, help for commands can be seen using some type of command line parameter.  So if you are at a cmd prompt and type: `del /?` You will see all the options you can use with the command.